# 'Run code' is not working in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-code-runner

When I click 'Run code' on the top right corner, or right click then click 'Run code', or use Ctrl+Alt+N, the integrated terminal does not appear and code could not run.

However, I can open the integrated terminal in vscode under View, and able to run code there using commands.

I believe my setting is correct as following. The problem happens suddenly, regardless of language.

```
"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\cmd.exe",
"code-runner.runInTerminal": true,
```

So How do I solve this to enable running code directly?

Comment: The 'Run Code' command works for me using python.  A python script is open in the editor window. I click on that area and then click the 'Run code' icon on the top right and it executed fine.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, and solved it by adding:

```
"folders": [
    {   
        "path": "."
    },
],
```

to my code-workspace file

Comment: I changed my machine so I don't know whether this will solve the issue. Other people having the same issue could give it a try.

Comment: Where is that workspace file please

Answer (score 1):

On my Mac, I opened up VSCode, then ctrl + ~, which opened up the terminal. I could then give manual commands there and make it run the program.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem, look how I had solve this problem with the help of my friends (Dipesh and Vinit).

Steps:

1. Open VS code
2. On the left bottom-corner click on Manage and go into the settings.
3. In the search settings type code runner, scroll-down and put tick-mark in 'Run In Terminal'.

After that check by running your code.

Answer (score 0):

the following worked for me:

1. Extensions
2. Type in search box 'Code Runner'
3. Install the extension (top most with over 2.5M downloads)
4. Restart VS Code
5. then go to: File > Preferences > Settings
6. Type 'code runner' in search box
7. under the section 'Run Code configuration', do scroll down until you find 'Code-runner: Run In Terminal' (code-runner.runInTerminal)
8. Check its box 'Whether to run code in Integrated Terminal'
9. You are done! Exit VS Code